# How to block all Windows 8 Internet connections?

Tags: windows-8, usb-modem

I have a PC with no access to wireless network, but there are people who can **accidentally** connect a 3g modem to it. It is always switched on with administrator logged in.

I want the computer not to connect to a modem and not to suggest it to a current user. (I.e. no application should be able to use the Internet)

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few options come to mind:

1. Disable all USB ports. Either through the BIOS or through Windows Device Manager. This might be inconvenient at some point if you want to use USB to transfer files, but it will absolutely stop any USB wireless devices from being used.
2. Install a [firewall](http://www.zonealarm.com/security/en-us/anti-virus-spyware-free-download.htm) configured to prevent all internet connections.
3. Another less secure way would be to use Windows Device Manager to disable all USB Wifi devices, and then configure the OS to stop automatically installing device drivers anytime something is plugged into a USB port. Step by step for configuring driver loading [here](http://www.microcentertech.com/tech_center/DB/read_article.php?faqid=./HowTos/HOW5006661B.htm).
4. Configure the computer to [Lock](http://www.it.cornell.edu/security/howto/screenlockhowwin.cfm) itself if unattended and require password login to continue using. You will also be able to use CTRL + ALT + DEL to bring up the option to lock the computer once you are done using it. The computer is still running and logged in, it is just secured from being quickly tampered with while it is unattended.
5. A combination of the above to suit your needs.